# Recursive iteration over an object in Jade template?

Tags: recursion, template-engine, pug

I have an object of mixed type properties - some strings, some arrays of strings, some objects containing arrays of strings - that can potentially go many levels deep.

I would like to iterate over all properties so that an object creates a div, an array creates a div, and a string property creates a span to contain the text.

```
{ "string" : "some text", "object" : { "array" : [ "text" ] } }
```

The above object would render as:

```
<span>some text</span>
<div>
  <div>
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But usually much more complex structures. How should I go about accomplishing this is Jade?

Answer (score 14):

It's been a while since you asked, but `mixin` is your friend, I think. I haven't tried it out, but if mixins support recursion, this should work:

```
mixin parseObject(obj)
  div
    - each val, key in obj
      - if (typeof val === 'string')
        span #{val}
      - else if (typeof val === 'object')
        mixin parseObject(val)
```

Then in the body of your .jade file, call `mixin parseObject(rootObject)`.

Comment: 3rd party here. I tried this, but the mixin does not seem to like recursion :(

Comment: As the original poster, I have updated your code to include `mixin` (thank **0x80**) and the proper `-` prefixes.

Answer (score 7):

Recursion seems to be suppported now. I have successfully used the function with a minor tweak; you need to use the mixin keyword when calling the function.

```
mixin parseObject(obj)
  div
    each val, key in obj
      if typeof val === 'string'
        span #{val}
      else if typeof val === 'object'
        mixin parseObject(val)
```

Answer (score 7):

In the modern version of Jade it's look like

```
mixin parseObject( obj )
  div
    each val in obj
      if typeof val === 'string'
        span= val
      else if typeof val === 'object'
        +parseObject( val )
```

Then in the body of your .jade file, call

`+parseObject( rootObject )`